# convert java object to json using jackson shows questionmark for this character ' – '

Tags: json, spring, jackson, pretty-print

I have code like below,

```
ObjectWriter objectWriter = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
String json = objectWriter.writeValueAsString(list);
```

My list contains some object with character ' – ' , its unicode is "&#8211"

But my json string shows there questionmark ('?').

Is there any fix for this?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Can you post your full JSON? That character seems to work fine for me.

Comment: storeTimings: "09:00 ? 19:20 (Sat ? Thur) 16:00 ? 21-00 (Friday)"
And the String in my database is :
storeTimings= "09:00 – 19:20 (Sat – Thur)             16:00 – 21-00 (Friday)"